# How to fill a column with a value based on a single row in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have panel data like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                 year = c("1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994"),
                 period = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, -3, -2, -1, 0))

 id year period
  a 1991     -1
  a 1992      0
  a 1993      1
  a 1994      2
  b 1991     -3
  b 1992     -2
  b 1993     -1
  b 1994      0
```

For each `id`, I want to create a column `first` that displays the `year` when `period = 0`. The ideal output:

```
 id year period first
  a 1991     -1  1992
  a 1992      0  1992
  a 1993      1  1992
  a 1994      2  1992
  b 1991     -3  1994
  b 1992     -2  1994
  b 1993     -1  1994
  b 1994      0  1994
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated, preferably using `dplyr` :)